# Azure's CosmosDB - Enable range index for strings once collection has already been created

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies) that you can enable range index for strings when creating the collection. Here is how you do it

```
DocumentCollection collection = new DocumentCollection { Id = "myCollection" };

collection.IndexingPolicy = new IndexingPolicy(new RangeIndex(DataType.String) { Precision = -1 });
collection.IndexingPolicy.IndexingMode = IndexingMode.Consistent;

await client.CreateDocumentCollectionAsync(UriFactory.CreateDatabaseUri("db"), collection);
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do it on the Azure portal and once the collection has already been created.

Thanks.

Comment: It's important to note that you'll see a significant difference in request unit usage if you enable range index on strings as they're indexed on insert. Unless you're using an eventual policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index policy can be changed any time, though either the portal or via API/SDK. And you can have both hash and range indexes for string properties.

You'll find the policy under Settings, and you can then update it as you see fit:

[image: default policy in portal]

Here's an example where I left the default range index for string, but added a hash index for the `/name` property path:

[image: new policy]